# Misaligned Pandas Correlation Matrix

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty bogged down with allergies and having trouble fixing this issue where the labels axis grid isn't lining up how I'd expect them to.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm   

def correlation_matrix(x):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 30)
    cax = ax.imshow(x.corr(),interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.title('Twitter Correlations')
    labels = [x.columns[i] for i in range(3, len(x.columns))]
    labels_dict = {labels[i]:i for i in range(len(labels))}
    plt.xticks(range(len(labels)),list(labels_dict.keys()),
               rotation='45', fontsize = 10.0)
    plt.yticks(range(len(labels)),list(labels_dict.keys()),
               rotation='45', fontsize = 10.0)
    fig.colorbar(cax)
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
    plt.show()

correlation_matrix(df)
```

Here's what the undesirable matrix looks like:

[Misaligned correlation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3J9N.png)

Anyone with experience with matrix visualization have any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT: FIXED THIS AS SOON AS I POSTED

In case anyone wanted to know, always check the data type of your columns beforehand. Problem was that timestamp column was still in string format, performed

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype('int')
```

which fixed the issue.

[Fixed correlation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjHEB.png)